# 1 dollar more vs. more than 1 dollar

Tags: semantics

A friend of mine has been arguing over the truth statement of: "1 dollar more vs. more than 1 dollar".

I am the one implying they're the same statement and convey the same semantic and logic; n < 1.

He fully disagrees they're the same thing in both the semantic and logic. Maybe it's cognitive dissonance.

Edit 1: 
Since the referral to context seems to be the current crux of the argument is being held into (which I get my argument does not stand that well on), then I might as well give what context these statements are used in; They're mostly for the field of machine learning and trying to extract value statements from the English language and reducing that to a comparative mathematical abstraction.

I'd also want to say me and my friend are trying not to look at this on contextual truths (but that is what he is I assume unconsciously doing) but more in the form devoid of higher level contextual truths. My erratic suggestion my friend is suffering from cognitive dissonance was not helpful without context. So apologies for that.

I want to re-iterate that I am not this forum bent on contextual functional truths. If that were the case then I would have used at least used the term "context" in my query. Apologies if this did not come off clear and if this question is fundamentally unanswerable when it comes to logical semantics.

I know some might not agree with me saying that semantics does not equal purely to just pragmatic or proper context use cases but to a more lower level abstraction of truth.

Edit 2:
I believe that there are more truths to what the statement was than just contextual truths.

Comment: You're using *cognitive dissonance* incorrectly, if that helps you adjust your assessment of your own command of the language and therefore your confidence in your position on this matter.

Comment: If you accuse your friend of cognitive dissonance just because he disagrees with you on a point of grammar, you could end up with one less friend than you have at the moment,  but that would not mean you had less than one friend.

Comment: @jiffyadvent It wasn't *erratic*, it was *erroneous*, and trying to stuff words like *erratic* and *query* into a sentence where *silly* and *question* would suit makes it seem like you're a teenager (misguidedly) trying to impress his English professor rather than someone with a strong command of English. Only little dogs feel the need to bark.

Comment: @jiffyadvent It's not animus, it's exasperation. I only point out your imprecise use of language because your question *explicitly asks* about the precise use of language, and I therefore want to give you a sense of proportion. I did not like that several people calmly and patiently explained to you that your position is ill-founded, and you continued to blithely ignore them and persist in your error, all the while (incorrectly) publicly tarring your friend for being "wrong about English". He wasn't, and you are, and I don't think we can make any headway unless you develop a sense of humility.

Comment: @jiffyadvent The answer is still no. If I have to put it coarsely (and therefore imprecisely, though the analogy should make the obstacle clear), in "more than one dollar", you are "getting" money; in "one dollar more", you are "putting" money. There is a agent and an patient in each, no matter how hard you try to avoid them or abstract them into oblivion, and *they're swapped* in the two phrases.

Comment: Mathematically I would express "1 dollar more" as  +1 and "more than one dollar" as >1.  Or "X is one dollar more than Y" as  priceof(X) = 1 + priceof(Y),  or "X is one dollar more" as adding  1 to priceof(X)    and X is more than one dollar as priceof(X) > 1.     But you are asking about how these phrases are used in English,. and they can only really be used in context, not in abstract, as English expressions. What you and your friend are doing is fascinating but seems to be well beyond the mundane issue of  the use  of English. The linguistics stack exchange might be able to help.

Comment: @davidlol Yes, `+1` vs `>1` is a helpful way to put it! But the linguistics stack isn't the place to ask: if he's concerned with what the phrases mean in English, then this is the place to ask; if he cares about transcendent logic, then he could ask on Philosphy.se, but in order to do that he'd have to render the statements in first-order logic notation, which would beg the question (that is, in doing translation, he'd necessarily have to *decide* the "true" meaning of the English phrases and embed that answer in his rendering). Since he's asking about NLP, the answer must arise from English.

Comment: @DanBron Given this example: https://youtu.be/UBVV8pch1dM?t=13s would you be able to discern what the initial assumptions of what "a dollar more" meant to the group of 3 people being asked?

Comment: @jadvent Yes, it's clear to everyone that the bat costs *a dollar more* than the ball, but most people don't think through the arithmetic before answering. *What* the bat costs more than, and by *how much*, is clear to everyone. And is another example of *a dollar more* means "relative to something" (in this case, the ball).

Comment: @DanBron Exactly! Maybe because they had an assumption of _"baseball"_ + $1 == $1.10 which is the additive math element that "+1" = "a dollar more" is meant to convey, that of which is what you agreed to as the mathematical representation of it. 

However, I do not think this is being asked by the interviewer; if it was then the **interviewees would have been right** he was conveying something along the lines of a "value greater than 1" and not "+1 to the value" of the _baseball_. I'm saying something does not fit here.

Comment: @DanBron So what would you say was wrong? 

Was it the initial contextual presuppositions that most people asked this question had? 

Or was it the mathematical representations the statements had devoid of context?

Comment: @jadvent I don't see it. The people are wrong because they have not thought through the arithmetic, not because the English is unclear. The English is completely clear, and I doubt you'd find anyone who disagreed that the interviewer's two statements are clearly and unambiguously equivalent to `bat+ball=$1.10` and `bat=$1+ball`. That people then draw the wrong conclusions from these two premises has no more bearing on the semantics of English than the fact that he first two dudes called said the earth revolves around the sun every 24 hrs bears on astronomy.

Comment: What was wrong was reasoning from premises. It's the same reason people get the wrong answers to those annoying "you're a math genius if you can answer this!!!! +=, /=???" memes going around on social media (which should demonstrate this has nothing to do with English). Most people have even thought about algebra since junior high, and weren't even good at it back then. The fact that everyone answers immediately, without even pausing to reason, tells you where the problem is: not in the problem statement, but in the method for deriving an answer.

Comment: Do you think if the interviewer had said instead "The bat has a cost greater than a dollar. How much does the ball cost?". Then would the initial assumptions be less prone arriving at the conclusion that the baseball costs $0.10?

Comment: @jadvent No, saying it that way is completely ambiguous (e.g. the bat could cost $1.10 and the ball be free, or the bat could cost $1.09 and the ball be $0.01), which aside from creating too many "right answers", will create an opportunity for even more and more creative kinds of wrong answers. The problem isn't English, it's people are bad at reasoning, and even worse at realizing they're bad at reasoning (which was the very point of the YouRube video). On this topic, I recommend "Thinking, Fast and Slow" by Kahneman, and, since you're interested in ML, "From AI to Zombies" on cog. biases.

Comment: Would you agree that one of the contextual issues with the question was that it was not using the phrase "a dollar more" in a precise comparative way?

The question should state that the bat is 1 dollar and 5 cents _more_ than the baseball, and **not** "one dollar more than the ball" to begin with. As the later statement **without** any additional context can be rendered completely useless and devoid of any contextual English semantic meaning from it. Unless we go back to extracting lower level truths from it such as there is an entity "n" which is  < 1" or "n <1".

Comment: @DanBron If so then what would "a dollar more" actually mean in English semantics? Is it completely and utterly gibberish **if** without context? Or is there anything it can mean on its own?

Comment: @jadvent No dude. The bat is precisely, exactly, and unambiguously one dollar, and only one dollar, **more** than he ball. That's the point. The *price* of the bat is $1.05, and the *price* of the ball is $0.05, but the bat is definitely *not* $1.05 **more** than the ball. The bat is *exactly* $1.00 more than the ball, which is *how we know both prices*. The *more* is comparative, as everyone keeps telling you, *not* absolute.

Comment: @jadvent And no, it is *not* gibberish without context. Look at my example of the movie "For A Few Dollars More": when it first came out, no one knew anything about it, *except that title*, and yet, without any other context, knew immediately and unequivocally that the sentence meant someone was asking for *more* dollars. Additional dollars. Dollars on top of other dollars. No context, completely unambiguous.

Comment: In other words: the use of the comparative  *more* **perforce creates** "an entity `n`", and no, you cannot know the absolute value of `n+1` without knowing the absolute value of `n`. All you know is there is now relatively *more*. Going back to the movie title: a few more dollars than *what*? We don't know, but now we want to find out!

Comment: Net-net:  You are wrong.  I'll let you decide which [behavior](http://anandavala.info/article/Despite-having-evidence-that-contradicts-someone%27s-belief-why-can%27t-they-come-to-believe-something-new.pdf) you're exhibiting.

Answer (score 1):

They're (usually) different. For example, if you have 10 dollar, and I give you *1 dollar more*, you now have 11 dollars. If I gave you *more than 1 dollar* instead, you would have had at least 12 dollars.

Comment: But the problem is, the use of *more* **implies** there's a known value to compare with - see Andrew's answer.

Comment: @jiffyadvent Glorfindel and your friend are right, as is Andrew Leach. The word *more* is -- to use a word you're fond of --- semantically, a *comparative*, so it *creates* a comparative context, merely by its use. See Andrew's answer for more details, and a good example in my comment underneath it, which I think you'll find difficult to argue with.

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same.

*More* is a comparative; it can always be followed by *than* and the noun or noun-phrase being compared.

*More than one dollar* is an obvious comparison: whatever amount you are considering is larger than a dollar: *x* > $1.

> - The money I have in my wallet is more than one dollar.
> - The price of this rug is more than one dollar.

*One dollar more* is a comparison where the "noun-phrase being compared" is not stated. But it can be filled in:

> - My wallet contains one dollar more ***than*** the amount yours holds.
> - This rug costs one dollar more ***than*** that one does.

That is, *one dollar more* **needs** *than* in order to make the comparison explicit. Without it, the comparison is implied from the context:

> My wallet contains one dollar more. (Context: discussing wallets)
>   This rug costs one dollar more. (Context: discussing rugs)

Thus "My wallet contains one dollar more" is not the same as "My wallet contains more than one dollar."

Comment: Precisely. Because *more* is a comparative, it *creates* a context of comparison, whether one pre-existed or not. The canonical example is the famous Western film [For A Few Dollars More](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0059578/). The first thing people would encounter about that movie is its title, which they'd read with not context or grammatical antecendants, and still know additional services were being offered for additional monies.

Comment: @jiffyadvent The "rational truth extraction" is just as Andrew and Glorfindel have it. You can continue to stick your fingers in your ears and sing la la la, but it doesn't change the facts.

Comment: @jiffyadvent Unfortunately, your request for vindication here will never go your way, because you're wrong, I'm afraid. The phrases are not the same. Dan has it right with "*more **creates*** a context," and in fact I wish I'd thought of it that way. Perhaps I shall add that in...

Comment: I want to re-iterate that I am not this forum bent on contextual functional truths. If that were the case then I would have used at least used the term "context" in my query. Apologies if this did not come off clear and if this question is fundamentally unanswerable when it comes to logical semantics.

I know some might not agree with me saying that semantics does not equal purely to just pragmatic or proper context use cases but to a more lower level abstraction of truth.

Comment: @jiffyadvent You keep making the same argument and you keep being told that argument is incorrect. I work for a machine learning startup, I understand the field, I understand your aims, and I'm also relatively well versed in English syntax and semantics (which is why I hang out on this site). If my product assigned the same truth value to both statements, I'd file a bug. They do *not* mean the same thing.

Comment: I've had enough of these comments on my answer. @jiffyadvent I suggest you write a new, entirely clear, question, referencing this one (in order that your new one does not get closed as a duplicate). However, if all you are interested in is whether "*x* more" is the same as "more than *x*" then I'm afraid you're out of luck. They are different, and actually context doesn't matter: the inclusion of *than* and *x* being on different sides of *than* (it's implied in "*x* more") is sufficient to make them different.

Comment: @jiffyadvent I'm assuming no such thing. I don't need to: you asked if the two phrases mean the same thing in English, either semantically, or logically, or both, and the answer is no. I don't need to know your "paradigm"\* to tell you that. If your "paradigm" is material, and you are therefore *not* simply asking whether the phrase mean the same thing is English or logic, then you've got a different question, one you haven't asked yet, and you should adjust your post accordingly. \*Seriously you're not doing yourself any favors here wearing out your thesaurus, it's working against you)